# Handle files bigger than memory with Keras

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am attempting to train a neural network on some medium sized data that i have in a dataframe(s). It is too big to handle in memory, but too small for a database type mechanism (spark). I can load most of the data into a sparse Data Frame ~60+ GB. However, when I try and pass portions of it to my keras serial NN using a generator, I end up getting a memory error.

I thought maybe splitting up the data and just loading numpy or pandas array/df and then feeding to the network would be the way to go,but everything I have read says that would just slow it down. I was wondering if there is another way that I just haven't found yet.... Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to use `numpy.load` with `mmap_mode='r'`? If you use this mode the file will not be loaded into memory.  You can than convert the mapped file to a numpy array in your generator.

Comment: I did not, but I can certainly try! Thanks!